# How can I control DC current into a battery charger using a microcontroller?

Tags: dc, solar-charge-controller

Apologies for the long question.

**Background**
I have a grid-tie solar setup at home with no battery. It exports unused power between 1-1000W at 250VAC when the sun is shining and we are not using all of the generated power,  essentially wasted power.

Solar -> inverter -> used watts -> wasted watts exported to the grid.

I also have a self-built mobile battery/inverter setup that I use for camping etc. It's a 24V system built around a pair of LiFePO4 100Ah batteries. I currently charge it with a pair of 400W solar panels (~80V/20A) fed into a 50A MPPT solar charger.

Solar -> MPPT charger -> 24V 200Ah battery

**Question**: I would like to charge my 24V 200Ah battery using the spare power from my grid-tie solar setup, so I need some way to control the DC current going into the solar charger, essentially emulating the solar panels but variable current that I can control with a micro-controller.

I've built a bunch of devices around the Arduino platform. I have the exported watts value figured out, but I don't understand what the AC to DC variable current part of the circuit should look like, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Why don't you charge it using the AC that is produced by your main grid-tied solar system inverter and not export quite as much energy to the grid?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do! But what device can I plug into my AC socket that will allow me to control how much power to take from the AC grid? Ie if I'm exporting 400Watts, how can convert that to DC to sent it to my batteries?

I want to take a variable amount of power depending of how many Watts are currently being exported, is there a DC device that will allow my to control the current from 0-1000W for instance? Kind of like a dimmer switch I guess.

Comment: Buy an AC powered battery charger that has that facility.

Comment: That would be perfect, but i cant find an AC charger with current control, is their a specific term i should be searching for? Or could you link to an example charger with that option?

Comment: Ive found a Victron 24v charger that allows me to charge to charge current between 15A and 30A via Bluetooth, i can automate that with an esp32. Its not granular and cant cope with the 50A current of a MPPT solar charger, but its a workable solution i guess.